# Powershell How to combine multiple lines in to one with comma

Tags: powershell

I have a very long list with 3 characters in each line like this

```
K2D
K5K
D9D
ILO
K5U
T8K
```

How can I use powershell to combine this list into one line separated by comma like this

`K2D, K5K, D9D, ILO, K5U, T8K`

I can add comma at end of each line as below but don't know how to combine them into one line.

```
$list = get-content "list.txt"

$result = "result.txt"

$comma = foreach ($line in $list){
         $begein = ""
         $end = ","
         $begin + $line + $end
}

SET-CONTENT $result -value $comma
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this -

```
"K2D
K5K
D9D
ILO
K5U
T8K" -replace ("`n", ",")
```

**Output -**

```
K2D,K5K,D9D,ILO,K5U,T8K
```

That would work for dynamic inputs. In case you are reading from a text file, you can use the `-join` operator like this -

```
$list = get-content "list.txt"
$list -join (",") | Set-Content $result
```

Comment: Wow.....that simple.....hummmmmmm. I will accept this answer after 2 mins

Answer (score 8):

Another approach would make use of knowing that `get-content` returns separate string items for each line:

```
(get-content -path $myFile) -join ', '
```

of if your input is already an array:

```
$myArray -join ', '
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I wanted to comment on Vivek Kumar Singh, but I do not have enough "reputation".
I wanted to thank him for his easy to use hint. It works like a charm!

I used it this way:
$MyText = $MyInputText -replace ("`n", ",")
Write-Host $MyText

My problem in the first place has been, that I wanted to convertfrom-json, resulting in an Array with multiline-strings.
Next Step was filling a CSV and here the multilines became a problem, because they created new rows.

My first idea was to take the raw content and do this
$MyText = $RetSearch.replace("\n",",")

ConvertFrom-Json : Nicht erkannte Escapesequenz. (1302974):

This Code instead was error-free, but did not change my problem, the "extra row" was still there:
$MyText = $RetSearch.replace("`n",",")

So only explicitly changing the string before writing it into the CSV did the trick.
So thanks again, maybe my answer might help someone with similar issues.